# Acesar propriedades de classe filha C#

Tags: c#, code-first

Usando code-first gerei a classe:

```
namespace take8.Models
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("takeeat.pessoa")]
    public partial class pessoa
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public pessoa()
        {
            pessoa_endereco = new HashSet<pessoa_endereco>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(1)]
        public string tipo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string razao_social { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string nome_fantasia { get; set; }

        [StringLength(14)]
        public string cpf_cnpj { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string rg_insc_estadual { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<pessoa_endereco> pessoa_endereco { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual usuario usuario { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual vendedor vendedor { get; set; }

    }
}
```

criei um controller com os metodos CRUD atraves da opção: **Controlador Web Api2 com ações, utilizando o entity Framework**, e foi gerado o controler:

```
namespace take8.Controllers
{
    public class pessoasController : ApiController
    {
        private ModelTake db = new ModelTake();

        // GET: api/pessoas
        public IQueryable<pessoa> Getpessoa()
        {
            return db.pessoa;
        }

        // GET: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getpessoa(int id)
        {
            pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Find(id);
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(pessoa);
        }

        // PUT: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult Putpessoa(int id, pessoa pessoa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != pessoa.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!pessoaExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/pessoas
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Postpessoa(pessoa pessoa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (pessoaExists(pessoa.id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = pessoa.id }, pessoa);
        }

        // DELETE: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Deletepessoa(int id)
        {
            pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Find(id);
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.pessoa.Remove(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(pessoa);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool pessoaExists(int id)
        {
            return db.pessoa.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Funcionou todos as operações (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) sem problemas. Mas queria acessar as propriedades da tabela pessoa_endereço, que é filha de pessoa, elas tem o relacionamento no banco de dados, o gerador trouxe a declaração

```
public virtual ICollection<pessoa_endereco> pessoa_endereco { get; set; }
```

O que preciso fazer para acessar essas propriedades?

Comment: O gerador trouxe uma lista de endereços para uma determinada pessoa, aonde você quer que mostre essa lista ??? em qual método?

Comment: Obrigado @Virgilio, mas analisando direito minha pergunta, não faz muito sentido eu querer juntar essas 2 tabelas, já que uma pessoa pode ter vários endereços, vi que não há necessidade no meu projeto disso, vou fazer consultas independentes.

Comment: Ok ... @Intenlider